# Jquery not working on page refresh; works otherwise

Tags: jquery, page-refresh

I have some jquery code on a page which does not work at all when the page is refreshed. It works when the page loads otherwise (as in from following a link or by hitting enter on the url-bar to load it).

I know that jquery isn't working at all because in console, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

And I do not get it when the page loads otherwise. Despite this error, I can see that jquery.min.js was loaded in the Network tab of developer tools.

I'm at a loss as to why this could be; I've never had this issue before. Other pages of the website load jquery fine when refreshed. Any help appreciated.

Per request, a code sample, straight from the page:

```
$('body').hide();
```

does not work on page refresh. No jquery works on page refresh.

Screenshots, if they help:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8VgR.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XznvS.png

Comment: How about starting by posting a code example in your question?

Comment: Okey should we guess what line the error is on?

Comment: The error is on the first line that jquery appears on the page. See code sample I edited above; the error occurs on that line.

Comment: Well that does not help very much. Show me some code

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/43qr1zK.png
http://i.imgur.com/GbmnX42.png

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you saw the page itself? http://www.ojmche.org/experience/annual-gala/sponsors_copy

Comment: Show your html code. Do a jsfiddle or something. You cannot just show one line, and make us guess whats wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70735/discussion-between-el3phanten-and-josh-burson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you load jQuery in your head.js function.
Try this instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: loading jquery outside of head.js worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are commenting out parts of this script tag may have something to do with it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">/*head.js(
/*      '/javascript/jquery.min.js',*/
        '/javascript/scripts-min.js',
        'http://js.addthisevent.com/atemay.js'
);*/</script>
```